# using And operator after "Then" of a If-condtion in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

part of my code looks as follows:

```
For i = 2 To Last Step 1
      If InStr(1, strg, Delim & ws2.Range("G" & i).Value & Delim, vbTextCompare) Then _
       ws2.Range("G" & i).EntireRow.Delete And i = i - 1

       Debug.Print i
Next i
```

The code works well without And-Part.
I get an error because of `i=i-1`. How can I say if the condition true do This `AND` That?

Comment: You simply have to write two expressions, as you did it with `print`.

Comment: Don't use `And`, use `:` - or you could wrap the two lines in an `IF..END IF`

Comment: And better use `ws2.Cells(i, 7)` insted of `ws2.Range("G" & i)`.

Comment: You could also loop backwards using `For i = Last to 2 Step -1`. That way you don't need the `i = i -1` line in the first place.

Comment: @maniA  have you read and tested the code in my answer below ? is it working for you as intended ?

Comment: yes sorry I was absence! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to perform multiple operations in case the `If` criteria is met, then you need to put each operation in a seperate line, and close the `If...` with an `End If`.

Try the code below:

```
If InStr(1, strg, Delim & ws2.Range("G" & i).Value & Delim, vbTextCompare) Then
    ws2.Range("G" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    i = i - 1
End If
```

You can delete an entire row also by using:

```
ws2.Rows(i).Delete
```